# Cannot draw a triangle in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I have recently started to learn OpenGL and have written a little bit of code to draw a simple white triangle in an SDL window. I have read and reread my code, and I have checked it against what was proposed in several opengl tutorials, but I can't make it work. I know that opengl is bound to SDL correctly because I can change the window background color with glClearColor, but I cannot display that darn triangle.

I would happily give out more information but to be honest I don't know any more precisely where the problem comes from, so here's the code I wrote :

```
int init()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL error : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Test OpenGL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create window. SDL error : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    gGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gWindow);
    if (gGLContext == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create OpenGL context. SDL error : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    GLenum glewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (glewInitResult != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize glew. Glew error : %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glewInitResult));
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gGLContext);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    return 0;
}

int loadShader(char *filename, GLint *shader)
{
    long sz;
    const GLchar *code;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if( !fp ) perror(filename),exit(1);

    fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell( fp );
    rewind( fp );

    code = calloc( 1, sz+1 );
    if( !code ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    if( 1!=fread( code , sz, 1 , fp) )
      fclose(fp),free(code),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);

    fclose(fp);
    char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    GLenum type;
    if (dot)
        type = !strcmp(dot, ".vs") ? GL_VERTEX_SHADER : GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &code, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    char buffer[512];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, sizeof(buffer), NULL, buffer);
    fprintf(stderr, buffer);
    if (status != GL_TRUE)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

void printError(char *message)
{
#define TEST(ERR) case ERR: fprintf(stderr, "%s : " #ERR "\n", message); break;
    int error;
    if ((error = glGetError()))
        switch (error)
        {
        TEST(GL_INVALID_ENUM)
        TEST(GL_INVALID_VALUE)
        TEST(GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
        TEST(GL_STACK_OVERFLOW)
        TEST(GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW)
        TEST(GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
        TEST(GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION)
        TEST(GL_TABLE_TOO_LARGE)
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Unknown error\n");
        }
#undef TEST
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (init() != 0)
        return -1;

    float vertices[] = {0.0,  0.5,
                        0.5, -0.5,
                        -.5, -0.5};
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vShader;
    GLuint fShader;
    if (loadShader("plain_2d.vs", &vShader) < 0)
        return -1;
    if (loadShader("plain_2d.fs", &fShader) < 0)
        return -1;
    GLint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    printError("Before entering the loop");

    SDL_Event e;
    int quit = 0;
    while (!quit)
    {
        printError("In the loop");
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
        {
            switch (e.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = 1;
            }
        }

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gWindow);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

printError and loadShader are helper functions that I wrote and am sure work perfectly. Here is the code for the vertex and fragment shaders, which is so basic I don't see how anything wrong could come from there :

VERTEX SHADER

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

FRAGMENT SHADER

```
#version 150

out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

I'm sorry that this is vague, but I did my research and really could not find anything wrong in my code, so I hope that a more experienced person will be able to find the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think your `loadShader` function does work properly? It could very well be, that the problem lies therein.

Comment: You should be checking your opengl for errors regularly.  You also never check to be sure your shaders compile without warnings (unless that happens in loadShader), and you never check the program for linker errors.

Comment: Try to call `glGetErrors()` in your loop. If if fires, find what line exactly triggers it.

Comment: I do check for errors, both when loading the shader (which is why I said it loaded correctly), and during the execution of the program with `printError(char *message)`. The code above signals no error, which is why I have a hard time figuring what's wrong with it. I added the code for both of these functions to my original post if you would like to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some checking on your code.  A few things that are wrong:

- You are not requesting a core profile
- You don't check your linkage
- You are abusing the comma operator
- You don't enable glewExperimental
- You don't clear your depth bit

Here's the diff from yours with context (from a modified version, since you didn't include headers or defines):

```
@@ -22,6 +22,7 @@

     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
+    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
@@ -43,6 +44,7 @@
         return -1;
     }

+    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
     GLenum glewInitResult = glewInit();
     if (glewInitResult != GLEW_OK)
     {
@@ -69,10 +71,10 @@
     rewind( fp );

     code = calloc( 1, sz+1 );
-    if( !code ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);
+    if( !code ) {fclose(fp);fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr);exit(1);}

     if( 1!=fread( code , sz, 1 , fp) )
-      fclose(fp),free(code),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);
+        {fclose(fp);free(code);fputs("entire read fails",stderr);exit(1);}

     fclose(fp);
     char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
@@ -122,6 +124,10 @@
     float vertices[] = {0.0,  0.5,
                         0.5, -0.5,
                         -.5, -0.5};
+    GLuint vao;
+    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
+    glBindVertexArray(vao);
+
     GLuint vbo;
     glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
@@ -160,7 +166,7 @@
         }

         glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
-        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
+        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

         glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

And the result: [image: triangle]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm on mobile right now but I will check those issues asap. If you don't mind me asking, what do a core profile and glewExperimental do? I also don't understand the "check your linkage" bit and I can't find the corresponding part in your modifications. I don't see how I am abusing the comma operator, to me this is just about syntax preferences but I could obviously be wrong. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I'll answer in multiple comments for readability.
Core profile allows post-OpenGL 3.2 features.  Many drivers allow you to ignore this, some don't.  It's always a good idea to enable it, though, as it disables deprecated features that you shouldn't be using anyway (and you aren't here).

Comment: glewExperimental is a hack that allows attempting to load an extension that isn't in a driver's experimental string.  glew itself is pretty dated anyway, I'd always suggest using [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) instead, if you can.  This will create a loader for a specifc version of the standard for you, so you can more easily target only a specific version of OpenGL.

Comment: "Check your linkage" means to check to be sure your shader program linked correctly.  Checking link status is almost just like checking shader compilation status:  https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Error_handling . I left those bits out of my modifications because it's a lot of bloat, and not actually required here to get the code functioning.  It should always be done in shader linking though.

Comment: The comma operator has a specific semantic use, which is to evaluate the left operand, and return the right.  It shouldn't be used as a hack to allow multiple statements in lieu of a block except where a block can not be used, like in the initialization of a for loop.  This is entirely up to personal style, but it's generally a good idea to use the comma operator only where you need to, or where it buys you a lot of extra flexibility, especially as it become difficult to read multiple statements on one line when function calls with commas are in the mix, or to add statements where you need.

Comment: To be clear, the only spots that were blocking drawing were clearing the depth buffer bit (because the depth buffer would prevent you from drawing in the same depth twice), enabling glewExperimental (because GLEW wasn't finding the extensions it needed), and creating and binding a VAO.  The rest is just "good idea" territory, rather than strictly necessary to get it to work in every case.  Feel free to ask if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Wow, that was very clear and helpful, thank you very much! I still have a bit of trouble understanding what each OpenGL does (binding, linking, using, enabling, disableing, attaching, clearing... You could rewrite Daft Punk's Technologic using only OpenGL calls), but it's beginning to make sense and I'll do my research before asking any more stuff.

Comment: No problem at all.  Modern OpenGL is pretty daunting if you haven't watched its development through the years, as a lot of it (nearly all of it, really) was added incrementally.  It's helpful to think of compiling and linking in the context of program compiling and linking (build objects from source, link objects into a program).  In the same way, you can also throw away your compiled shader objects (unbind them and delete them) after successfully linking your program.  That's actually the recommended way to do things unless you plan to link them again, to save space and useless variables.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't generated and bound a vertex array object, just a vertex buffer. Essentially you have created a data source (the VBO) but nowhere for the data to go, so there is no array object bound when you call `glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);`

Add the following before you generate and bind your buffer:

```
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
```

Edit: There is a default VAO available in 3.1 and newer *only* when the compatibility profile is enabled - the core profile requires you to do it manually.

Also, please show the source for `loadShader()`

Comment: I'm not sure if that would make much difference, given that there is a default VAO bound from the beginning.

Comment: @Taywee I tested it locally, albeit with glfw not sdl. IIUC it depends on GL version - the default VAO will only work for core>=3.1 if you're in compatibility mode.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat correct afaik, with some possible weirdness from nvidia (non spec compliant?)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I have added the code you wrote, but I still get a black - or whichever color I choose - screen. I'm also still confused about VBOs and VAOs. If I understand correctly, a VBO is a low level array storing the vertice info in the graphics card, whereas a VAO is a "profile" which stores info about what to render and how -  is that correct, or somewhat close to the reality? As for `loadShader()`, I added the code to my post.

Comment: @Toctave That's more or less correct. VAOs manage client-side (i.e. not on the GPU) state like vertex layout and which VBO to use when you want to draw an array.
Learning OpenGL is pretty tough because you are essentially catching up on years of development.

I see Taywee fixed your remaining issues; I missed that you didn't enable the core profile.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you create shaders, you have to specify the shader type:

```
GLuint vertexShader, fragmentShader;

vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

I don't see any of that in your code.  Does loadShader do this detection based on the extension?  That would be the most likely problem if not.

Comment: Thank you for your response. `loadShader()` does exactly that, I added the code to my original post if you would like to check it out.